# How to extract text, with link and text after the link and another text after br with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have parsed the following `string` to BeautifulSoup to extract data out of it but I can't get some of the data out. Having tried different methods. I managed to get out the the text between the `<a>` tag, the links and the text outside of each link.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p align="left">
   <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
    <b>
     <font size="4">
      GOVERNOR:
     </font>
    </b>
    <br/>
   </font>
   <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
    <a href="http://governor.alabama.gov/">
     <strong>
      Robert 
                Bentley (R)*
     </strong>
    </a>
    - Ex-Morgan County Commissioner &amp; State Correctional Officer
    <strong>
     <br/>
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com/stacy.george.3139">
      Stacy George 
                (R)
     </a>
     - Ex-Morgan County Commissioner &amp; State Correctional Officer
     <br/>
     Bob Starkey (R) - Retired Businessman, '10 State Rep. Candidate &amp; '12 Scottsboro Mayor Candidate
     <br/>
     <a href="http://www.bassforbama.com/">
      Kevin Bass (D)
     </a>
     - Businessman &amp; Ex-Pro Baseball Player
     <br/>
     <a href="http://www.parkergriffithforcongress.com/">
      Parker Griffith 
                (D)
     </a>
     - Ex-Congressman, Ex-State Sen., Physician &amp; Ex-Republican
    </strong>
   </font>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my implementation with BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(Above_String)

"""for br in soup.find_all("br"):
    print br
    #print br.nextSibling.content
"""
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if link.string == None:
        print link.strong.string, link.get("href"),link.next_sibling
    else:
        print link.string, link.get("href"),link.next_sibling,link.next_sibling
```

The above code prints out something like this:

```
> Robert 
                Bentley (R)*
      http://governor.alabama.gov/ 

>      Stacy George 
                (R)
      http://www.facebook.com/stacy.george.3139 
     - Ex-Morgan County Commissioner & State Correctional Officer

>      Kevin Bass (D)
      http://www.bassforbama.com/ 
     - Businessman & Ex-Pro Baseball Player


>      Parker Griffith 
                (D)
      http://www.parkergriffithforcongress.com/ 
     - Ex-Congressman, Ex-State Sen., Physician & Ex-Republican
```

Missing out the third item which is

```
Bob Starkey (R) - Retired Businessman, '10 State Rep. Candidate &amp; '12 Scottsboro Mayor Candidate
```

Please how do I get around this using BeautifulSoup?
I have tried to do it with `find_all("br")` but it doesn't work as `br` tags return `NoneType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab *all* text nodes beyond each link:

```
from itertools import takewhile
from bs4 import NavigableString

not_link = lambda t: getattr(t, 'name') not in ('a', 'strong')

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print 'Link contents:'
    text = link.text.strip()
    for sibling in takewhile(not_link, link.next_siblings):
        if isinstance(sibling, NavigableString):
            text += unicode(sibling).strip()
        else:
            text += sibling.text.strip()
    print text
```

This prints:

```
Link contents:
Robert 
                Bentley (R)*- Ex-Morgan County Commissioner & State Correctional Officer
Link contents:
Stacy George 
                (R)- Ex-Morgan County Commissioner & State Correctional OfficerBob Starkey (R) - Retired Businessman, '10 State Rep. Candidate & '12 Scottsboro Mayor Candidate
Link contents:
Kevin Bass (D)- Businessman & Ex-Pro Baseball Player
Link contents:
Parker Griffith 
                (D)- Ex-Congressman, Ex-State Sen., Physician & Ex-Republican
```

Comment: I appreciate this help and it works. As part of learning, is there another way of doing it without using itertools because since am new I am thinking if there are other ways without importing anything else? Since am a beginner in Python and never used some advanced stuff like itertools. Only learnt Python couple of weeks ago and challenging myself.

Comment: @user3428883: You can loop over `next_siblings` with a `for` loop and use `break` to end that loop when you get to the next sibling that isn't interesting anymore.

Comment: @user3428883: that's really all that `takewhile` does; loop over `next_siblings` and give you everything until the `lambda` function returns `False`, ending the loop.